# Cursor GameObject vanishing after some time

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
cursors.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cursors.transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), 10f * Time.deltaTime);
```

I want to make a cursor that moves smoothly and not instant towards the mouseposition, and for a few seconds, it works, then vanishes within a few seconds, anyone know why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask you, is your cursor game object a 2D object that you want to move along the screen ( x, y coords only ) or you want to move it in world space ( z axis is included ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor might be moving through the camera's clipping plane
You could try:

```
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
mousePos.z = 0;
cursors.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cursors.transform.position, mousePos, 10f * Time.deltaTime);
```